# Sql query to select records for a single distinct customer id

Tags: sql

I have written a query for sales by customers in groups it is as follows:

```
SELECT customerid,
SUM (salestax1)As total_salestax1,
SUM(total_payment_received) As total_payment_recieved,
COUNT (orderid)as order_qty,
SUM(paymentamount)As paymentamount
 FROM Orders_74V94W6D22$
WHERE orderdate between '7/6/2011 16:35' and '2/3/2012 11:53'    
GROUP BY customerid
```

but this query shows only 5 fields but I need to show following fields:

```
orderid    billingcompanyname    billingfirstname    billinglastname    
billingcountry    shipcountry    paymentamount creditcardtransactionid    
orderdate    creditcardauthorizationdate    orderstatus    
total_payment_received    tax1_title salestax1
```

then how to deal with it?

Comment: Which DBMS? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to understand what GROUP BY means.
If you are grouping by customerId, you will have only one customer because all data is `grouped` into it.

How do you want to group by `orderid` and display the `orderid` on your result set? If you have 10 order ids, do you expect 10 rows on the result? If yes, fine, group by it but I don't think that's what you want

EDIT:

Well, this is NOT a good idea, your table structure is WRONG and I dont think you fully understand that a group by means, BUT I think this query will get your result:

```
 SELECT customerid, 
 (select top 1  [column1] from Orders_74V94W6D22$ where customerid = ORD.customerid),
 (select top 1  [column2] from Orders_74V94W6D22$ where customerid = ORD.customerid),
 (select top 1  [column3] from Orders_74V94W6D22$ where customerid = ORD.customerid),
 SUM (salestax1)As total_salestax1, 
 SUM(total_payment_received) As total_payment_recieved, 
 COUNT (orderid)as order_qty, 
 SUM(paymentamount)As paymentamount
 FROM Orders_74V94W6D22$  ORD
 WHERE orderdate between '7/6/2011 16:35' and '2/3/2012 11:53' 
 GROUP BY customerid
```

Comment: I want to group by customerid

Comment: so your query seems fine. What's the problem?

Comment: actually your query is working but i want single row for single customerid

Comment: if you are grouping by customerid, you should have one row per customer

Comment: Select distinct c.[column1], c.[column2], c.[column3], tbl.*
From Orders_74V94W6D22$ c inner join (
 SELECT customerid,
SUM (salestax1)As total_salestax1,
SUM(total_payment_received) As total_payment_recieved,
COUNT (orderid)as order_qty,
SUM(paymentamount)As paymentamount
 FROM Orders_74V94W6D22$
WHERE orderdate between '7/6/2011 16:35' and '2/3/2012 11:53'    
GROUP BY customerid 
) as tbl on tbl.customerid = c.customerid      this query is working but it shows multiple rows for single table can you help me out?

Answer (score 1):

To select more about the customer, you need to use your query as a sub query, something like:

```
Select distinct c.[column1], c.[column2], c.[column3], tbl.*
From Orders_74V94W6D22$ c inner join (
 SELECT customerid,
SUM (salestax1)As total_salestax1,
SUM(total_payment_received) As total_payment_recieved,
COUNT (orderid)as order_qty,
SUM(paymentamount)As paymentamount
 FROM Orders_74V94W6D22$
WHERE orderdate between '7/6/2011 16:35' and '2/3/2012 11:53'    
GROUP BY customerid 
) as tbl on tbl.customerid = c.customerid
```

but you cant logically select something about 1 order as youve grouped multiple orders

Comment: but i have only one table orders

Comment: `[` is not allowed in a column name in standard SQL

Comment: your query is working but I want single row for single customerid

Comment: @a_horse: seriously, the [brackets] were for fill in the blanks!

Comment: I have not used the brackets but directly c.columnName

Comment: it returns distinct rows, you must be selecting something that appears more than once - what is your exact top query select statement? if you've some "order" column in there, then ur gonna get dupes man